# Find all vertices with the same edge attribute

Tags: python, graph, igraph

I would like to find **all vertices (vertex id's) sharing the same edge attribute** (so there can be tons of vertices like this) by using Igraph. This would be very convenient when I want to find all "villages" (the vertices of my graph) on a "road", let's say "Route 69" (an edge attribute).

Is there a simple way in Igraph to do this? Maybe I've overcomplicated it.

Actually what I need is the opposite of: `g.es.select(_within=g.vs[2:5])` or

```
>>> men = g.vs.select(gender="m")
>>> women = g.vs.select(gender="f")
>>> g.es.select(_between=(men, women))
```

because I know the edge attribute but I don't know the vertices.

I will select the edge and hope that it will return all related vertices.

Maybe I'm only tired now, but I don't find my way around this problem. I appreciate if somebody helps me out with the right way. Or maybe there is a method I miss in [tutorial](http://hal.elte.hu/~nepusz/development/igraph/tutorial/tutorial.html) and documentation. It smells like there is a very simple method to this. **Thank you in advance for any advice!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, select all the edges on Route 69:

```
edges = g.es.select(name="Route69")
```

Then iterate through the selected edges and collect the endpoints of the vertices:

```
vertices = set()
for edge in edges:
    vertices.update(edge.tuple)
```

This will give you a set containing the vertex IDs of all the vertices that are incident on at least one edge with name `Route69`. If you need a VertexSeq, you can simply do this:

```
vertices = g.vs[sorted(vertices)]
```

Comment: Thank you Tamás once again. This solution worked and it's very simple to implement.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do the following:

```
r69edges = g.es.select(name_eq='Route69')  #Select all edges where name=='Route69'
sg = r69edges.subgraph()  #Create a subgraph containing only the selected edges (and attached vertices)
village_verts = sg.vs.select(name_eq='villages')  #Select the vertices where name=='villages'
```

This assumes that 'villages' and 'Route69' are stored in an attribute called 'name' on the vertices and edges...  Adjust appropriately to match your attributes.

Of course - you can squash this all into one line if you want:

```
village_verts = g.es.select(name_eq='Route69').subgraph().vs.select(name_eq='villages')
```

Not sure if this is the most efficient way (though I'm not seeing any shortcuts in the documentation), but it should get you what you're after.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Probably not the most efficient but works as well.